# SMQT Matlab Code (THE SUCCESSIVE MEAN QUANTIZATION TRANSFORM)

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with smqt in MATLAB is there any source code of smqt function? I want customise this function for better use.

Answer (score 1):

and finally ...

```
function M = SMQT(V, l, L)
if l>L 
    M = zeros(size(V), 'like', V);
    return;
end
meanV = nanmean(V(:));
D0 = V;
D1 = V;
if not(isnan(meanV)) 
    D0(D0 > meanV) = NaN;
    D1(D1 <= meanV) = NaN;
end
M = not(isnan(D1)) * (2^(L-l));
if l==L 
    return;
end
M0 = SMQT(D0, l+1, L);
M1 = SMQT(D1, l+1, L);
M = M + M0 + M1;
end
```

Have fun .. ;)

to use :

```
lena = imread('c:\matlab\lena_gray_256.tif');
M = uint8(SMQT(double(lena),1,8));
imshow(M);
```

Comment: How would you use this function? You don't make any references to the `SMQT(V, l, L)` you have defined.